# How to apply Role based authorization after login in cakephp 2.7?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

I'm new on cakephp . I have implementd a code for login and I m trying to providing Role based action for differecnt users.
Such as I have a table in which i store id and role (Admin,Normal,SubAdmin).
I want that super admin can add delete update and edit and view everones record.
Admin can only edit and delete add users and cant delete/edit his record.
How could i achieve this.

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do by use this code

In your App Controller :

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components =array(
                   'Session',
                    'Flash',
                   'Auth'=>array(

                   'authenticate' => array(
                    'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array('username' => 'Email','password'=>'Passward'),
                    )),
                    'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'Users','action'=>'index'),
                    'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'Users','action'=>'login'),
                     'authError'=>"You Can't access this page",
                     'authorize' => array('controller')
                  )
                    );

 public function beforeFilter()
 {
     $this->Auth->allow('index');
 }
 public function isAuthorized($user)
 {
        return  true;
 }
 }
```

In your Users Controller:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

 public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','Session','Flash');
 public function beforeFilter()
 {   
     parent::beforeFilter();
     $this->Auth->allow('add');
 }
 public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // The owner of a post can edit and delete it
    if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete'))) {

    switch ($user['Role']) {
      case "Super user":
        return true;
        break;
      case "Admin":
        if($user['id']==$this->request->params['pass'][0])
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
        break;
      default:
          return false;
    }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: is this helpful code if I have more than one controller with many actions and have many deifferent view in different folders with the same name of controllers.

Comment: please provide your code or  give brief explanation what you exactly want to do  so i can understand your problem.